# В графе есть ребра с отрицательным весом. Можно ли добавить веса всем и использовать алгоритм Дейкстры?

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Допустим есть граф с ребрами отрицательного веса и на нем надо провести алгоритм поиска кратчайшего пути от вершины s до v, но cо следующим подходом: добавим к каждому весу ребра одно и тоже положительное число, так чтобы вес каждого ребра стал положительным, а затем проведем на нем алгоритм Дейкстры. Будет ли работать с этом случае такой подход? Если да то можете объяснить почему?

Comment: Нет. Потому что *число ребер* в разных путях может быть разным...

Comment: Представьте самый простой пример: три ребра веса -1: A-B, B-C, A-C. И найдите путь от А до С...

Comment: @Harry вы говорите что нет, тогда можете привести контрпример в пользу этого

Comment: Смотрите, например, АБ — 2, БВ — -1, АВ — 2. Кратчайший — АБВ. Прибавим... ну, по 2. Теперь имеем АБ — 4, БВ — 1, АВ — 4. Кратчайший теперь АВ. Такой контрпример устроит? Еще раз — обратите внимание на *разное количество ребер* в кратчайших путях.

Comment: @Harry да устроит, спасибо

Comment: Про это немного рассказывается в данной стратье: [Алгоритм Джонсона на орграфе с отрицательными дугами](https://habr.com/ru/company/otus/blog/510942/)